# Check if two lat long are close enough to be same Python

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table in PostgreSQL which contains latitude and longitude of certain Places. And I am using flask-sqlalchemy to query the postgres database. like this:

```
query = db.session.query(Places).all  # Place is the Modal class
```

Now I am insert values in database like this:

```
 user = Places(request.json['key'], request.json['place_name'], 
              request.json['latitude'], request.json['longitude'])

 db.session.add(user)
```

My primary key is `user.key` to avoid duplication of record. But I also want to avoid insertion of those records which have a lat/long close enough to the ones which are already present in database.

For example:  the following lat/long are present in db `28.704661, 77.101484` now I don't want the db to allow insertion of values close enough to this lat/long.
So, when I try to insert this `28.704420, 77.101167` then it should give me an error.
One thing I though was to check up-to three decimal places after decimal and not allow a input of less than six decimal places.But as given on the answer on this page[Accuracy of lat long](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude/8674#8674) which says that near equator 1 degree of change can vary upto 111 kilometer and so on. I thought a better approach could be found out.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `postgis` and set this 'closeness' restriction as a constraint on the table.

Comment: that is a nice idea. I attempt to try that. can you give a sample query as in to what to use. I guess ST_Distance  would work.

Comment: _near equator 1 degree of change can vary up to 111 kilometer_ implies that  0.001 degrees (3 decimal places) varies 100 m. How do you define "close"? If 100m is not close enough, pick a 4 decimal places or 5. Using a more precise measure of distance between points is likely going to overcomplicate your code. Keep it simple like Euclidean distance between the points must be greater than some epsilon.